# Вывод данных из массива в таблицу pdf, используя pdfmake.js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть многомерный массив такого вида

```
var arr = [["1","2","3","4"],["5","6","7","8"]];
```

данные в массиве динамически меняются и собираются через цикл и
соответсвенно его длина неизвестна.

Далее из этого массива нужно передать данные в pdf, который создается при помощи pdfmake.js

При помощи такого кода

```
{
    table: {
        body: 
             arr.map(function(item) {
                 return [ {text: item} ]
             })
    },
},
```

мне удалось создать таблицу, в которой есть строки, и в каждой строке есть текст с содержимым массивов.

т.е. у меня в таблице в строке всего 1 ячейка и в ней 1234
в другой строке тоже 1 ячейка и в ней 5678

а мне нужно получить 4 ячейки, чтобы в каждой было соответсвующее значение.

Никак не пойму как это сделать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось достаточно просто - нужно использовать два вложенных map:

```
var arr = [["1","2","3","4"],["5","6","7","8"]];


var dd = {
    content: [
        {text: 'Table', style: 'header'},
        {
            table: {
                body: 
                    arr.map(function(item){
                        return item.map(function(subitem){
                            return {text:subitem}
                        });
                    })
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Можно проверить скопировав код [сюда](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

Comment: такое бывает когда плохо понимаешь))
большое спасибо!